# Are the Mars elevation data publicly available?

Tags: mars, reference-request

Is it possible to get the data on Mars terrain somewhere? Something like [SRTM](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) data for Mars.

Ideally in a format like this:

```
X,Y,E
```

where X and Y are coordinates of the region and E is the elevation (altitude) in that region.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two sources:

- [MOLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Laser_Altimeter) laser altimetry (http://tharsis.gsfc.nasa.gov/mapping_data.html) with the actual data available from MEGDR (Mission Experiment Gridded Data Records) at http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mgs/megdr.html (the closest analog to SRTM you can get, but at a higher fidelity level).
- and DTM (digital terrain models from [stereo pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry)) (http://www.uahirise.org/dtm/).

DTM coverage is small, but the resulting topo models are awesomely detailed - they are good for assessing landing sites and building hi-fi virtual terrains at great locations (Marineris, Olympus etc.) One such example is the terrain model for the fictional Ares 3 landing site from Andy Weir's [*The Martian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel)) available [here](http://www.uahirise.org/dtm/dtm.php?ID=ESP_041277_2115).

Please note that lava tubes/subsurface features aren't generally resolvable from either MOLA or DTMs and one has to go through the list of known tubes to guesstimate how far the <strike>li'l green man</strike> rabbit hole goes.

Comment: Thanks. If you wanted to create a Minecraft map of Mars, which data set would you choose?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko - haven't played Minecraft, for global coverage there's only MOLA. Landing sites/great locations can be built from DTMs (Marineris, Olympus etc.)

Comment: If I were you, I would choose a more local area to do a map in, and use the HiRISE DTMs. With those, you have the imagery, and the elevation, perfect for making a map from.